# Запрос на выборку из двух таблиц с условием

Tags: mysql

Есть вот такой запрос

```
select
  `works`.*, count(`like`.`wid`) as likes
from
  `works`, `like`
where
 `works`.`id` = `like`.`wid`
group by id
```

и соответственно я получаю данные где `` `works`.`id` = `like`.`wid` ``, а как мне сделать так, чтобы если в таблице `like` нет записи где `` `works`.`id` = `like`.`wid` `` то `` count(`like`.`wid`) as likes `` равнялось бы 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто используйте `left join`.

```
select `works`.*, count(`like`.`wid`) as likes 
    from `works` 
        left join `like` on `works`.`id` = `like`.`wid` 
    group by id
```